# MS edge not support send keys in text field in local website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am doing automated tests on MS Edge, I am unable to do send keys to the text field of my local website.

I am using Python 2.7 and a proper version of MicrosoftWebDriver.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import string
import unittest
import random
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import json
import sys

def runtest():
    driver.set_window_size(1280, 900)
    driver.get("http://localhost/project/interio/interio/");
    time.sleep(1) # Let the user actually see something!
    loginfinal = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='AdminLogInFinal.php']") #for login
    loginfinal.click()
    Login_name= driver.find_element_by_name('user')
    Login_name.send_keys('09')
    test6 = Login_name.get_attribute('value')#.encode('utf-8')
    print test6
    Login_password= driver.find_element_by_name('pass')
    Login_password.send_keys('se')
    test7 = Login_password.get_attribute('value')#.encode('utf-8')
    print test7
    driver.quit()

driver = webdriver.Edge("MicrosoftWebDriver.exe")
runtest()
```

Errors: Edge does not perform send keys

```
C:\python code>python localwebsitetest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "localwebsitetest.py", line 36, in <module>
    runtest()
  File "localwebsitetest.py", line 23, in runtest
    Login_name= driver.find_element_by_name('user')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 365, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: No such element
```

I have tried only find element by id but it does not work.

Here is my code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import string
import unittest
import random
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import json
import sys


def runtest():
    driver.set_window_size(1280, 900)
    driver.get("http://localhost/project/interio/interio/");
    time.sleep(1) # Let the user actually see something!
    loginfinal = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='AdminLogInFinal.php']") #for login
    loginfinal.click()
    Login_name= driver.find_element_by_id('user')




driver = webdriver.Edge("MicrosoftWebDriver.exe")
runtest()
```

*Error*

```
C:\python code>python localwebsitetest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "localwebsitetest.py", line 29, in <module>
    runtest()
  File "localwebsitetest.py", line 23, in runtest
    Login_name= driver.find_element_by_id('user')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 269, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: No such element
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? It looks like your indentation might be off.

Comment: It is throwing NoSuchElementException: Message: No such element for Login_name= driver.find_element_by_name('user'). Can you check you selector and its value and check whether you are able to find element or not. Try using any other selector and then try to execute the code.

Comment: when i try to find element by id above mentioned error occured kindly help

Comment: You appear to be selecting by the `href` attribute, not an `id`. You could try reducing the selector to `//a` temporarily to see if this succeeds, and if so try to send the read HTML to a file, in case it is not loading for some reason.

Comment: kindly help to find which type of exception i am getting in error which package is missing?